# using c# to open an image using hfs file system

Tags: c#, image, hfs

Seems like an odd request. I want to take in an image file probably a .dmg or a .bin, which uses HFS file system. Ideally id like to mount the image because all i need to do is get certain files from it, I don't need everything. They probably will be quite big files. Id be very grateful if I got some advice. Where do I start?

Simplifying answers as much as possible would be great also. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to port [HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html) to C# I would recommend you just use it...